# How do you make a object that always follow another object?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, movement

I'm trying to make a game object follow another game object and switch to another when a button is pressed. But right now it just seems to change the position when the button is pressed but it doesn't follow the object. How can I make it follow the other object?

```html
public Transform PosObjOne;

public Transform PosObjTwo;

public Transform PosObjThree;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("UseVr"))
    {
        PosObjThree.position = PosObjTwo.position;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("NoVr"))
    {
        PosObjThree.position = (PosObjOne.position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well right now the position only gets set when you press the button, so there is no continuous loop that is setting the position after pressing your button once.

To keep the object at the other object's position you could make use of a boolean that is set to true once you press the button, and revert back when you press the other button again. Then in na if statement check the boolean's value and set the correct position.

For example:

```
public Transform PosObjOne; 
public Transform PosObjTwo; 
public Transform PosObjThree; 
bool FollowOne = true;

void Update () { 
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("UseVr")) { 
        FollowOne = false;
    } 

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("NoVr")) { 
        FollowOne = true
    } 

    if(FollowOne) {
        PosObjThree.position = PosObjOne.position; 
    } else {
        PosObjThree.position = PosObjTwo.position; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a little problem with the code. When you press the button "UseVR" *PlayerThree* does follow *PlayerTwo* but only for as long as the button is **pressed**. As you stop pressing the button, the `if` statement is `false`, and it stops following PlayerTwo, and same happens with the follow PlayerOne's `if` statement. So we need to insert a concept that follows the expected Player even after the button is pressed once.
So making a `bool` variable, `childOf_Two` will solve the problem.

Declare the variable `childOf_Two` after declaration of three `Transform` variables.

```
private bool childOf_Two;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("UseVr"))
    {
        childOf_Two = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("NoVr"))
    {
        childOf_Two = false;
    }
}
```

Now we know that `childOf_Two` will be true just after the button is pressed, and will be `true` for as long as you do not press another button. So now we want our PlayerOne to follow PlayerTwo  after `childOf_Two` is `true`. 
So we will say that,

```
if (childOf_two == true)
{
    PosObjThree.position = PosObjTwo.position;
}
if (childOf_two == false)
{
    PosObjThree.position = PosObjOne.position;
}
```

We will write this inside `Update()` after the previous code. So now it will follow PlayerTwo as long as the value of `childOf_Two` stays `true` and will be same for PlayerOne.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

you just can change reference to FollowGoal by any moment you want.

````
Transform FollowGoal;
Transform Enemy1;
Transform Enemy2;

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDow(KeyCode.1)) 
    {
        FollowGoal= Enemy1;
    }    

    if(Input.GetKeyDow(KeyCode.2)) 
    {
        FollowGoal= Enemy2; 
    }

    Transform.position= Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, FollowGoal.position,speed);
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Using physics joints may be the simplest approach to having one object follow another. Here is the Unity documentation on pyhsics joints: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints.html